# Bootstrap 4 datepicker appears behind bootstrap 4 Modal

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 for creating a modal that contains some inputs and a datepicker using [this](http://gijgo.com/datepicker/example/bootstrap-4) plug-in, everything works fine but when I click on the datepicker field to select a value the datepicker appears behind the Modal.

I already checked some answers here but all said that I must change the `z-index` value of the datepicker element so it can appear on top of the Modal but that did  not work for me. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In the css I added:

```
.datepicker { 
    z-index: 999 !important;
}
```

Note the "!important".